# Erro ao abrir emulador no Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debug, emulador

Estou com um erro aqui no Android Studio, quando vou *debuggar* a App
no emulador, ele não abre e aparece o seguinte erro:

> "emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!"

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Como diz a mensagem, você precisa instalar o módulo HAXM.

1. Abra o SDK Manager
2. Vá em SDK Tools
3. Marque a opção do HAXM Installer.
4. Vá na pasta apontada no seu Android SDK Location e execute o intelhaxm-android.exe para instalar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, garante que o `HAXM installer` está insalado no seu SDK Manager, como na figura a seguir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após o download do componente, execute seu insalador via linha de comando:

**`{SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe`**

Observação: No Android Studio, o comando "intelhaxm.exe" fora trocado por "intelhaxm-android.exe"

Se lhe for mostrado o erro "**VT not supported**" durante a instalação, desabilite o Hiper-V em "Windows Features (Ativar ou desativar recursos do Windows)". Outra maneira de se desabilitar o Hiper-V é executando o seguinte comando: `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`. Finalmente, você necessita habilitar "Virtualization Technology" na sua BIOS.

Comment: valeu pela ajuda amigo , fiz o q vc mencionou , mas n consegui instalar o tal haxm :( .. aparece um erro , dizendo q eu tenho q ativar o VT , sendo q ja ativei o mesmo pela bios .. qual será a solução para isso?

Comment: Desculpe a demora em lhe responder... qual mensagem de erro aparece?